# Applications of knot theory to biology/pharmacology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, applications, mathematical-biology, medicine

What are the applications of knot theory to biology/pharmacology?

I guess there should be some, since proteins are quite long and some of their properties are probably related to whether they are knotted or not.

---

Some related questions:

- [Applications of knot theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48222/applications-of-knot-theory)
- [Applications of group theory to math. biology (pharmacology) ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94907/applications-of-group-theory-to-math-biology-pharmacology)
- [Any applications integrable systems (pde,ode, q-,...) to math. biology (pharmakinetics, pharmadynamics) ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94840/any-applications-integrable-systems-pde-ode-q-to-math-biology-pharmakin)
- ["Graphical models" and "gene finding and diagnosis of diseases" ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94931/graphical-models-and-gene-finding-and-diagnosis-of-diseases)
- [Mathematics and cancer research?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87575/mathematics-and-cancer-research)

Comment: In my experience, the "applications" of knot theory to these fields are fairly elementary and really don't use any deep theory, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I kind of ask a similar question to a researcher doing maths for biology once, like "did someone use symmetry theories with a significant impact in biology ?" (I had in mind the Noether theorem and relatives). His answer : "it seems it is not enough to apply known theorems of math-phy to math-bio, it really needs new technology and objects". 

Answer (score 3):

In the end of [this](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/RTang.pdf) paper by Loius Kauffman and Jay Goldman, they use some properties of rational tangles to deduce the different ways in which DNA can recombine. I think I have seen other papers that do similar things.

Answer (score 1):

A web search on  DNA and Knot Theory yields hits, for example

http://www.tiem.utk.edu/~gross/bioed/webmodules/DNAknot.html

Answer (score 1):

Some papers on knots and proteins:

- William R. Taylor, [A deeply knotted protein structure and how it might fold](https://doi.org/10.1038/35022623), Nature, Volume 406, pages 916–919, August 2000.
- Michael A. Erdmann, [Protein similarity from knot theory: geometric convolution and line weavings](http://doi.org/10.1089/cmb.2005.12.609), Journal of Computational Biology, Volume 12, Issue 6, pages 609-637, July 2005.
- Firas Khatib,  Matthew T. Weirauch,  Carol A. Rohl, [Rapid knot detection and application to protein structure prediction](https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btl236), Bioinformatics, Volume 22, Issue 14, pages e252–e259, July 2006.
- Peter Virnau, Leonid A. Mirny, Mehran Kardar, [Intricate knots in proteins: function and evolution](https://dx.doi.org/10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.0020122), PLoS Computational Biology, September 2006.
- Rama Mishra, Shantha Bhushan, [Knot theory in understanding proteins](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00285-011-0488-3), Journal of Mathematical Biology, Volume 65, pages 1187–1213, December 2012.

---

Related:

- [Applications of knot theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48222)
- [Measures of entangledness of an open curve](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132513)